# How to use groupby method combine several (use slice?) columns or rows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know that using group by method can combine several columns or rows by using theirs label, but if I wanna combine several columns by calculate theirs mean or standard deviation like this:

```
      a1  a2  a3  b1  b2
A1    5   8   9   5   0
A2    0   1   7   6   9
A3    2   4   5   2   4
B1    2   4   7   7   9
B2    1   7   0   6   9
```

But this now work at all:

```
df.loc[:, 'a'] = df.groupby(['a1': a3']).mean()
```

It says cannot using ":", but it's really hard to list all the labels like this:

```
df.loc[:, 'a'] = df.groupby(['a1', 'a2',  a3']).mean()

      a  b
A1    x  x
A2    x  x
A3    x  x
B1    x  x
B2    x  x
```

In the same way, how about the rows?

```
      a1  a2  a3  b1  b2
A      x   x   x   x   x
B      x   x   x   x   x
```

So what's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5,8,9,5,0], [0,1,7,6,9], [2,4,5,2,4], [2,4,7,7,9], [1,7,0,6,9]],
                  index=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2'],
                  columns=['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2'])
a_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('a')]  # or use any other criterion to select the columns
# e.g. to select columns a51:a100, you can use something like:
# a_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('a') and int(col[1:]) >= 51]
df['a'] = df[a_cols].mean(axis=1)
print df

    a1  a2  a3  b1  b2         a 
A1   5   8   9   5   0  7.333333      
A2   0   1   7   6   9  2.666667      
A3   2   4   5   2   4  3.666667      
B1   2   4   7   7   9  4.333333      
B2   1   7   0   6   9  2.666667
```

Another method by using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(lambda col: col[0], axis=1).mean()  # or use any other function to select columns
# e.g. to select columns a51:a100, you can use something like:
# lambda col: col if col.startswith('a') and int(col[1:]) >= 51] else 'other'
           a    b
A1  7.333333  2.5
A2  2.666667  7.5
A3  3.666667  3.0
B1  4.333333  8.0
B2  2.666667  7.5
```

Rows:

```
df['prefix'] = df.index.map(lambda x: x[0])  # or any other criterion 
print df

    a1  a2  a3  b1  b2         a prefix
A1   5   8   9   5   0  7.333333      A
A2   0   1   7   6   9  2.666667      A
A3   2   4   5   2   4  3.666667      A
B1   2   4   7   7   9  4.333333      B
B2   1   7   0   6   9  2.666667      B

df.groupby('prefix').mean()              

              a1        a2   a3        b1        b2         a
prefix                                                       
A       2.333333  4.333333  7.0  4.333333  4.333333  4.555556
B       1.500000  5.500000  3.5  6.500000  9.000000  3.500000
```

Comment: And can I do the same thing for columns? Like:   df['prefix'] = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[0])?

Comment: For the lambda part, is this doing the work to set the range of the rows?

Comment: Or if I've got a dataframe, and it has a1, a2, ... a100, for the columns, I only wanna combine a51 ~ a100 by their means, how can this work?

Comment: lambda part creates a new column `prefix`, which is then used to group the rows. I've expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: Added an example for `a51-a100` to the answer: `a_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('a') and int(col[1:]) >= 51]`

Comment: OMG, thanks sooo much, but I've got one more, if the column labels are datetime string, such as 0101, 0102,.... 1231, how can I combine January 's data by using mean?

Comment: So is this looks like this?  [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('01') and int(col[2:3]) <= 31]

Comment: `And can I do the same thing for columns? Like: df['prefix'] = df.columns.map(lambda x: x[0])?` - yes, I've added an example to the answer

Comment: `if the column labels are datetime string, such as 0101, 0102,.... 1231, how can I combine January 's data by using mean?` -> you can use the groupby approach (see the part 2 of the answer) with `lambda col: col[:2]`. It will group by months.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127071/discussion-between-kurosaki-and-dennis-golomazov).